# POST data by ajax to another controller in yii2

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, yii2

I am new to yii. I am trying to pass a list of parameters from js to my controller in the event of 'on click' of a button. 
My code is (in the view named 'ostan' in url:http://localhost/web/site/):

```js
var url ='http://localhost/web/';
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn").click(function(){
    
    var vname = $("#name").val();
    var vemail = $("#email").val();
    if(vname=='' && vemail==''){
        alert("Please fill out the form");
    }else if(vname=='' && vemail!==''){
        alert('Name field is required')
    }else if(vemail=='' && vname!==''){
        alert('Email field is required')
    }else{
        $.post(url+"Category/Gett",{name:vname,email:vemail},function(response,status){ 
            alert("*----Received Data----*\n\nResponse : " + response+"\n\nStatus : " + status);
            $("#form")[0].reset();
        });
    }

});

});
```

```html
    <form id="form" method="post">
    <div id="namediv"><label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/><br></div>
    <div id="emaildiv"><label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/></div>
    
    <button id="btn">Send Data</button>
    </form>
```

Controller code:

```
public function actionGett()
{

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"]; 
    echo "Welcome ". $name ."!";  

}
```

Comment: what's the problem ?   .. you have an error ?

Comment: Yes, Does not work.
Does not return any value

Comment: have you check in browser console if you have eg: 404 error?

Comment: yep, i have 404 error

Comment: i ahve posted an answer  with a  first suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function `actionGett()` is in a `CategoryController` class, you should post your form to `url+"category/gett"` instead of `url+"Category/Gett"`. More info on how Yii2 creates routes from controllers, actions, modules, etc. [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#creating-controllers).